# Show that the vectors (ε1, ε2, . . . , εn−1) and (ε1ε2, ε2ε3, . . . , εn−1εn) have the same distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, vectors

Let ε1, ε2, . . . , εn be independent random signs. Show that the vectors (ε1, ε2, . . . , εn−1) and (ε1ε2, ε2ε3, . . . , εn−1εn) have the same distribution. In particular, the variables ε1ε2, ε2ε3, . . . , εn−1εn are independent. Are the variables ε1ε2, ε2ε3, ε3ε1 independent?

Is this referring to the cross product? then shouldn't independence be obvious since cross product of pairs of vectors are independent of each other? I do not understand the distribution part, however. Please explain.

Comment: Do we have $P(\epsilon_i=1)=0.5=P(\epsilon_i=-1)$ for every $i$?

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: Elaborate? I am just asking you some info.

Comment: i dont understand your question thats why i asked

Comment: it didnt specify in the question but i assume every vector would be identical

Comment: I would say P(ϵi=1)=p P(ϵi=-1)=1-p

Comment: Then if $p\neq0.5$ the distribution of $\epsilon_1$ is not the same as the distribution of $\epsilon_1\epsilon_2$ so the vectors cannot have equal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If $P(\epsilon_i=1)=0.5=P(\epsilon_i=-1)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ then this is an answer.

$\begin{aligned}P\left(\epsilon_{1}\epsilon_{2}=1\right)=P\left(\epsilon_{1}=1=\epsilon_{2}\right)+P\left(\epsilon_{1}=-1=\epsilon_{2}\right)=P\left(\epsilon_{1}=1\right)P\left(\epsilon_{2}=1\right)+P\left(\epsilon_{1}=-1\right)P\left(\epsilon_{2}=-1\right)=0.5^{2}+0.5^{2}=0.5\end{aligned}
$

and likewise $P\left(\epsilon_{2}\epsilon_{3}=1\right)=0.5$

$\begin{aligned}P\left(\epsilon_{1}\epsilon_{2}=1\wedge\epsilon_{2}\epsilon_{3}=1\right) & =P\left(\epsilon_{1}\epsilon_{2}=1\wedge\epsilon_{2}\epsilon_{3}=1\mid\epsilon_{2}=1\right)P\left(\epsilon_{2}=1\right)+P\left(\epsilon_{1}\epsilon_{2}=1\wedge\epsilon_{2}\epsilon_{3}=1\mid\epsilon_{2}=-1\right)P\left(\epsilon_{2}=-1\right)\\
 & =P\left(\epsilon_{1}=1\wedge\epsilon_{3}=1\mid\epsilon_{2}=1\right)0.5+P\left(\epsilon_{1}=-1\wedge\epsilon_{3}=-1\mid\epsilon_{2}=1\right)0.5\\
 & =P\left(\epsilon_{1}=1\wedge\epsilon_{3}=1\right)0.5+P\left(\epsilon_{1}=-1\wedge\epsilon_{3}=-1\right)0.5\\
 & =P\left(\epsilon_{1}=1\right)P\left(\epsilon_{3}=1\right)0.5+P\left(\epsilon_{1}=-1\right)P\left(\epsilon_{3}=-1\right)0.5\\
 & =0.5^{3}+0.5^{3}=0.25
\end{aligned}
$

This gives $P\left(\epsilon_{1}\epsilon_{2}=1\wedge\epsilon_{2}\epsilon_{3}=1\right)=P\left(\epsilon_{1}\epsilon_{2}=1\right)P\left(\epsilon_{2}\epsilon_{3}=1\right)$
and because the rv's $\epsilon_{1}\epsilon_{2}$ and $\epsilon_{2}\epsilon_{3}$
can only take values is $\left\{ -1,1\right\} $ this proves that
they are independent.

Further $\epsilon_{i}\epsilon_{i+1}$ and $\epsilon_{i}$ have equal
distributions so the vectors $\left(\epsilon_{1},\dots,\epsilon_{n-1}\right)$
and $\left(\epsilon_{1}\epsilon_{2},\dots,\epsilon_{n-1}\epsilon_{n}\right)$
have equal distributions.

Comment: please tell me why would you assume $P(\epsilon_i=1)=0.5=P(\epsilon_i=-1)$

Comment: is it because independent random signs suggest that + or - sign are random so P(+)=P(-)=1/2? also what does rv mean? r, v are two vectors?

Comment: rv stands for random variable. As said in former comment: if $p\neq0.5$ then the vectors cannot have equal distribution. That's why I preassume that $p=0.5$.